# Appending all elements in one Linked-list to the end of another list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having trouble writing a method that appends all elements in a method's parameter list to the end of another list. The method is supposed to return true if the list was changed, and false otherwise.

For example, if the original list was 1->6->5, and the other list is 3->8->2. After the call, the list is now 1->6->5->3->8->2.

I'm having trouble with the Boolean return statements as I am confused how they link into the logic of the list. I also don't know how far the pointers need to move in order to append the lists. The whole thing can be done in one loop but I don't know how.

```
public boolean appendList(DynamicList othrList) {
  for (DynamicNode tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp.getNext()) {
    if(tmp == null) {
      DynamicNode ex = otherList.getList;
      tmp.setNext(ex);
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Full code:

```
public class DynamicNode {
  private Object info;        // the data in the node
  private DynamicNode next;   // refers to the next node on the list

  public DynamicNode(Object x, DynamicNode n) {
    info = x;
    next = n;
  }

  public Object getInfo() { return info; }
  public DynamicNode getNext() { return next; }
  public void setInfo(Object x) { info = x; }
  public void setNext(DynamicNode n) { next = n; }
  public String toString() { return info.toString(); }
}

class DynamicList {
  private DynamicNode head;

  public DynamicList() { head = null; }
  public DynamicList(DynamicNode head) {  this.head = head; }

  public boolean isEmpty() { return head == null; }
  public DynamicNode getList() { return head; }

  // The problem
  public boolean appendList(DynamicList othrList) {
    for (DynamicNode tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp.getNext()) {
      if(tmp == null) {
        DynamicNode ex = otherList.getList;
        tmp.setNext(ex);
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `boolean` return value supposed to indicate? If it is like the standard [`List.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) return value, it always returns `true`, so you just code a `return true;` statements are the end of the method.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I've added the code I have tried

Comment: @Andreas the return value is supposed to indicate if the list was changed or not. So if it changed its supposed to return true and false if it hasn't

Comment: I've removed comments and condensed methods to make it easier for us to scan through your code and see the method in question.

Comment: @K.Xiang Then start method with `if (othrList.isEmpty()) return false;`, then do the logic of copying the nodes of `othrList` into the end of `this` list, and finally `return true;`.

Answer (score -1):

For the code in question (with comments in the code holding additional explanation).

**This does fulfill the requirement: "if the original list was 1->6->5, and the other list is 3->8->2. After the call, the list is now 1->6->5->3->8->2."**

It appends the elements(nodes) so after appending both list share the same nodes. Which should be okay. However this implies that if a node in "othrlist" changes after appending, it will also change in the list. Often this is the expected behavior. 
So it is "shallow" and does not create any unessary (deep-)copies of elements.

**To sum up this behaves the way, the aproach the op choose in his method does**: One(!) loop, only appending and not duplicating.

```
public boolean appendList(DynamicList othrList) {
    DynamicNode tmp = head;
    if(tmp == null) { //special case empty list
        head = othrList.getList();
        return null != head; //early exit, list changed if head is no longer null.
    }
    while (tmp.getNext() != null) tmp = tmp.getNext(); //search for the last element
    tmp.setNext(othrList.getList()); //link last element to head of other.
    return null != tmp.getNext(); //list changed if tmp.next is no longer null(as it was before).
}
```

Comment: This will leave both lists sharing some nodes, which is not appropriate. The nodes of `othrList` must be copied.

Comment: @Andreas correct it does. the list is not copied but appended as the op requested. That means  the othrList continues to exist on and becomes the tail of the list. Copying was not requested and would be a (formaly) wrong implementation as of requirement: "the list" itself has to be appended not just the values in it.

Comment: Question says *"append all **elements**"*. It doesn't say "append all *nodes*". The *elements* are the values / data / `info` in the nodes.

Comment: Well lets see what is usefull for the op. If the op states, that his requirement is to copy in oposite to append I gladly add another loop, that copies.(as this is why I am writing an answer: hoping to help out the op with a problem he has)

Comment: If you believe it is unclear whether OP needs to append *nodes* or append *elements* (even though question says *elements*), then you should have asked for clarification in a comment.

Comment: No I don't believe that.  I believe you are interpretating and adding your own made up requirements that are not  requirement of the ops posts. What  gives you the idea that nodes may not be shared by the lists? While your interpretation may make sense in some contexts(i give you that) the op doesn't make up such a case. Also from an educational point of view It seems more logical to first learn to append.